# Create a table using jquery inside razor view

Tags: jquery, html, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a table inside razor view.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:80%">
    @if (ViewBag.IsGlobal == 1)
    {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnViewLocal").prop("disabled",true);

                @foreach (var item in Model.GlobalNewsModel)
                {

                    var gTable = "<tr class=\"tvl\">";
                    gTable += "<td>";
                    gTable += "<input id=\"testid\" value=\"testvalue\" class=\"form-control\" />";
                    gTable += "<td>";
                    gTable += "</tr>";
                    //gTable.append("#wholeNews tr:last").after(gTable); <-- I tried it like this it also not working.
                }
                $("#WholeNews tr:last").after(gTable); // I can't place thisone inside foreach loop,it's unrecognize the $
            });
        </script>
    }
}
</div>
```

### Then

I hardcoded that table without `foreach` loop and it's working.But my requirement is to put that one in inside foreach loop.for your reference i've put that one here.

```
var gTable = "<tr class=\"tvl\">";
gTable += "<td>";
gTable += '<input id="' + $(this).closest('tr').find('td :eq(0)').val() + "newsno" + '" disabled type="text\" class=\"form-control" value="' + $(this).closest('tr').find('td :eq(0)').val() + '">';
gTable += "</td>";
gTable += "</tr>";
$("#WholeNews tr:last").after(gTable);
```

Comment: Your `@foreach()` loop is razor code and is parsed on the server before the view is sent to the browser. Javascript does not exist at that point. Why are you not just creating the table using razor/html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making the loop on the client:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsGlobal == 1)
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnViewLocal").prop("disabled", true);

            // serialize the server side model on the client
            var news = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GlobalNewsModel));

            // loop through the news javascript variable on the client
            for (var i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
                // here you can access news[i] if you need to print
                // some values from your model in the table

                var gTable = "<tr class=\"tvl\">";
                gTable += "<td>";
                gTable += "<input id=\"testid\" value=\"testvalue\" class=\"form-control\" />";
                gTable += "<td>";
                gTable += "</tr>";
                gTable.append("#wholeNews tr:last").after(gTable);
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Also note that if you don't need to access `news[i]` on the client then you probably don't need to serialize your model, all you need is the length:

```
var newsLength = @Model.GlobalNewsModel.Length;
for (var i = 0; i < newsLength; i++) {
    ...
}
```

but I guess you need the model values. Also notice that you can project only the values that you really need on the client to avoid wasting unnecessary space in the markup:

```
var news = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GlobalNewsModel.Select(x => new
{
    foo = x.Foo,
    bar = x.Bar,
})));
for (var i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
    // you can access news[i].foo and news[i].bar here
    ...
}
```

Comment: var news = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GlobalNewsModel));  It shows me Underline the semicolon in red color and Syntax Error.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the buggy Visual Studio Razor Intellisense is showing you. Are you even looking at it? Did you try running the code? I suggest you do hit `F5` and enjoy the results.

Comment: I tried your first code but it nothing project to the screen.

Comment: Did you inspect the markup? Does it look alright? Are you getting some javascript errors in the console?

Comment: That's normal. You have declared `gTable` as a string. Of course that it wouldn't have an `append` method.  Now fix your javascript code and you will be good to go. Don't just blindly copy-paste from StackOverflow.

Comment: Finally fixed document.getElementById('wholeNews').innerHTML = gTable;